# The purpose of acoustic optical modulator (AOM) in Heterodyne Interferometry for Plasmas

Tags: optics, laser, interferometry

I do not understand the purpose of an acoustic optical modulator (AOM) in a heterodyne interferometry system. Take the system below as an example (taken from a UW Dissertation)

[image]

My understanding for a homodyne interferometry system suffers from 1) amplitude variations and 2) phase ambiguity around phi=0,n*pi,...  However, is it acceptable to know that your phase shift will initially be positive and design your system to ensure your phase shift will always be <2*pi so as to eliminate phase ambiguity from your system?

Finally, what is the purpose of the beat frequency the AOM introduces?  My best guess is it either that it defines an 'averaging' period each point is at the beat frequency because you cannot digitize 532nm laser beam's phase.

Comment: The RP Photonics Encyclopedia is often a good place to start. [Acousto-Optic Modulators](https://www.rp-photonics.com/acousto_optic_modulators.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, is it acceptable to know that your phase shift will initially be positive and design your system to ensure your phase shift will always be <2pi

Sure, but that's going to limit the optical path-length difference you can measure pretty severely.

If you want an interferometer that can measure displacements of more than a fraction of a micron, it's not an option.

If you're using a path through some material that changes due to the condition you want to measure (temperature, pressure, or whatever) then it limits the sensitivity of that measurement.

> what is the purpose of the beat frequency the AOM introduces?

As you say, it gives you a signal at a frequency that's convenient for measuring frequency or phase.

Without it, if the optical path length changes very slowly, then the received signal also changes quite slowly, and if your receiver electronics have some "DC drift" behavior it could result in erroneous measurement. With the beat frequency present, the DC drift can be eliminated by measuring only AC components of the signal.